# Pulling Google Variable Into Hidden Field

Tags: google-analytics, marketo

I've started parsing out the Google UTMZ_ cookie and am looking for any possible way to push that information into Marketo hidden fields. I currently create and populate Marketo hidden fields based on Google Tracker fields, but I can't figure out how to do it with the fields in the attached image.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddiQY.png]

I'm wondering if anyone has any insights into how I could push those fields to a form. Below is the code I use for pushing Google Tracker fields to Marketo.

```
MktoForms2.whenReady(function(form){   
  ga(function(){   
    form.addHiddenFields({   
      GA_User_ID__c : ga.getByName('gtm1').get('userId')   
    });   
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Universal Analytics [does not use utm cookies](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage#analyticsjs), and it does not have custom variables (they have been replaced by custom dimensions), so your version of the GA code does not match the information from your screen shot.

Since campaign attribution is now done completely on the Google servers you can no longer get the information via client side GA code. You would either have to pull that information via the API (which I do not think is feasible in runtime) or build your own solution to try and match Google's campaign attribution ([as displayed here in a flowchart)](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205762?hl=en#flowchart).